# Why is the position for my UISlider in my Iphone 4s different than all my other devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I positioned my slider in the middle of the screen and it is positioned correctly in all my devices except for the 4s. I cant figure out how to make it so that the slider is in the middle of the screen like all the other devices instead of to the right. Here is the code Im using:

[image]

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {

        let scaleFactor = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 320


        middleSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRectMake(125 * scaleFactor, 153 * scaleFactor, 150, 50))
        middleSlider.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.value = 1.0
        middleSlider.continuous = true
        middleSlider.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view?.addSubview(middleSlider)
}

if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {

        let scaleFactor = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 320
        middleSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRectMake(130 * scaleFactor, 650, 200, 150))
        middleSlider.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        middleSlider.value = 1.0
        middleSlider.continuous = true
        middleSlider.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view?.addSubview(middleSlider)

}
```

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Im in spritekit so no.

Comment: You are using `UIKit` so you can use autolayout

Comment: How would I use it in spritekit?

Comment: you can simply use `CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width/2 - 150/2, 153 * scaleFactor, 150, 50)` will be centered on all devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the Slider you can simply do as follows

```
middleSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width/2 - 150/2, 153 * scaleFactor, 150, 50));
```

And it also will be centered for all devices.

Comment: It centered correctley but the height in the 4s is a bit high compared to the other devices. How would I fix that?

Comment: @coding22 Would suggest to use another approach for height...
I suppose it should be more or less the same hight from the bottom, so you can do something like `self.view.bounds.height - 50 - 120` in your `CGRectMake`...

Comment: @coding22 Keep in mind that iPhone 4/4s has 320 points width so the line ` let scaleFactor = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 320 ` will give you "1.0" on iPhone 4/4s

Comment: But if it should be Centered Vertically as well than the same Approach would fit ` CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.width/2 - 150/2 , self.view.bounds.height/2 - 50/2 , 150 , 50)`

Comment: I used this and it worked: self.view!.bounds.height/2 * 1.7 for the height.

Comment: i think it is the same as self.view!.bounds.height * 0.7  not sure though my math is Horribad :)